# Vacation visa requirements to Jamaica

Tags: visas, nigerian-citizens, jamaica

I am a Nigerian citizen on vacation in the US and would like to visit Jamaica for two weeks do I need a Jamaica visa?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you do need an entry visa. The information is [here](http://www.congenjamaica-ny.org/visas/requirements-2/) from the New York consulate and extracted below:

Note: When I look for the visa processing fee, there was a footnote for Nigerian applicants:

> *N.B. In order to obtain a visa, Nigerian Nationals will need to provide the Consulate with a letter of invitation from individuals
>   they are visiting or organization they will be working with in
>   Jamaica.

**General Conditions for Admission**

A person desirous of visiting Jamaica:

1. Should be in possession of a valid visa unless exempted from this requirement under any of the prescribed regulations.
2. Must be in a position to support himself/herself and accompanying dependents for the duration of stay;
3. Should not be of unsound mind;
4. Should not be the subject of a certificate submitted to the Immigration Officer by a health officer indicating that for medical reasons, permission to land is not desirable;
5. Should not have been sentenced in a foreign country for any extraditable crime within the meaning of the Extradition Acts 1870 and 1906;
6. Should not be the subject of a deportation order in force under the Aliens Law, Chapter 9;
7. Should not be the subject of a landing prohibition order from the Minister of National Security;

**TOURIST VISA**

1. Valid passport
2. One passport size photograph
3. Completed Visa [Application Form J](http://www.congenjamaica-ny.org/wp-content/members/admin/assets/pdf/JamaicaVisaApplicationForm.pdf) (signature is required)
4. Valid return visa to the United States
5. Flight itinerary (Round trip ticket)
6. Visa fee payable by Money Order to the Jamaican Consulate, 767 Third Avenue, New York, NY 10017 (fees are applied as listed: USD20)
7. FedEx fee of $20.00 payable by Money Order to return passport (if applicable)

Processing time: Walk-in applicants: 2-3 business days; mailed-in applicants: 5 business days

A further requirement is listed on the bottom of the page:

> Also must be presented is proof of vaccination against Measles,
>   Rubella and Polio. The Certificate of Proof must be dated after 12
>   August, 2014.